# What is the difference between the results using different AR(p) estimation methods?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, autoregressive

There are three different ways to do AR(p) estimation.

1. OLS
2. MLE
3. Yule=Walker Equation

What are the differences between the results using these three methods?

// http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/~tanizaki/class/2014/model_analysis1/08.pdf